# Query that Counts records with a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, where-clause

```
                SELECT 
                EmailOfConsumer, 
                COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) as 'NumberOfOrders',
                SUM(CAST(Total as money)) as 'TotalValue',
                (SUM(CAST(Total as money))/COUNT(EmailOfConsumer)) as 'AverageValue'
                FROM webshop
                GROUP BY EmailOfConsumer 
                ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

This brings back:

```
EmailOfConsumer NumberOfOrders  TotalValue                AverageValue
test                   1              2000000000.10           2000000000.10
```

I would like to add a search on `WHERE NumberOfOrders = '1'`

I have tried adding `WHERE COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = '1'`

but I get this error:

```
    An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a 
HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

Comment: Why are you comparing numerical values to strings?  For example, `COUNT` returns an `INT` and comparing it to `'1'` rather than `1` is peculiar.  Comparing to an empty string is even stranger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = 1
```

The having clause restricts a aggregate whereas the where clause only put restrictions on individual column data

Comment: Or add "HAVING TotalValue/AverageValue = 0". BTW: I suggest NOT to use '1' as the value, rather real number 1 (without ' ) otherwise MySQL casts strings and it will be less efficient. Also HAVING is very slow, it works after the query finished processing - so it is considered a bad practice to use it.

Comment: HAVING clause is added after the GROUP BY clause and before ORDER BY

Comment: @JackJiang would you know how to add this HAVING clause only if the value is not null?

Comment: Which value are we talking about here. I ask this because COUNT() only counts the number of Non-NULL values

Comment: @JackJiang only include this if the countVar is not null '(HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = countVar)'

Comment: What is countVar? You can use a conditional HAVING clause if you wish.

Comment: How would you do that? I want to show all values if i write `HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = NULL`

Comment: Again I ask what is CountVar? COUNT() cannot return a NULL value

Answer (score 2):

Using group by and then having clause. Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
SELECT 
            EmailOfConsumer, 
            COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) as 'NumberOfOrders',
            SUM(CAST(Total as money)) as 'TotalValue',
            (SUM(CAST(Total as money))/COUNT(EmailOfConsumer)) as 'AverageValue'
            FROM webshop
            GROUP BY EmailOfConsumer 
            HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = '1'
            ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
                EmailOfConsumer, 
                COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) as 'NumberOfOrders',
                SUM(CAST(Total as money)) as 'TotalValue',
                (SUM(CAST(Total as money))/COUNT(EmailOfConsumer)) as 'AverageValue'
                FROM webshop
                GROUP BY EmailOfConsumer 

HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = '1'
                ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT 
            EmailOfConsumer, 
            COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) as 'NumberOfOrders',
            SUM(CAST(Total as money)) as 'TotalValue',
            (SUM(CAST(Total as money))/COUNT(EmailOfConsumer)) as 'AverageValue'
            FROM webshop
            GROUP BY EmailOfConsumer 
            HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = 1
            ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add filter condition in `HAVING clause`. **Also COUNT returns numeric value so no need to add quote to check it** :

```
SELECT     EmailOfConsumer, 
           COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) as 'NumberOfOrders',
           SUM(CAST(Total as money)) as 'TotalValue',
           (SUM(CAST(Total as money))/COUNT(EmailOfConsumer)) as 'AverageValue'
           FROM webshop
           GROUP BY EmailOfConsumer 
           HAVING COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) = 1
           ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

You can't check condition with `COUNT in WHERE clause` because it will execute before aggregation, so you need to check it after aggregation in `HAVING clause`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT 
    EmailOfConsumer, 
    COUNT(EmailOfConsumer) as 'NumberOfOrders',
    SUM(CAST(Total as money)) as 'TotalValue',
    (SUM(CAST(Total as money))/COUNT(EmailOfConsumer)) as 'AverageValue'
FROM webshop
GROUP BY EmailOfConsumer 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY TotalValue DESC
```

Notes:

- `WHERE` clause *precedes* `GROUP BY`, while `HAVING` clause *follows* `GROUP BY`
- `WHERE` clause filters rows *before* aggregation; `HAVING` clause filters aggregated rows
- `COUNT(...)` returns a number, so the constant `1` should *not* be enclosed in quotes.