# SQL query that combines 2 into 1, specifically it counts the number of people in each group for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I've found a few posts in here that are similar, but doesn't work with what i'd like to do...

similar post: [Trying to write a query that counts multiple things with different where cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330811/trying-to-write-a-query-that-counts-multiple-things-with-different-where-cases)

similar post: [Query that Counts records with a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098378/query-that-counts-records-with-a-where-clause)

what I want to do is I have some... 200 groups, and within those groups are people with specific application dates. I want a count of how many people are in those groups that have a application date that falls within a specific range.

So this is the first method i've been using, but it only works for 1 group at a time

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM membersapplication ma
INNER JOIN members mb on mb.mbr_id = ma.mbr_id
WHERE (GPL_ID = 20179) and (ma.mpl_effectivedate >= '2/01/2015' and ma.mpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015') and (ma.mpl_cancellationdate is null)
```

This code takes the count of anyone that falls under GPL_ID 20179 (group placement id), i have 200 GPL_ID's that I would like this to run for, there is never a duplicate GPL_ID.

```
SELECT Gr.GPL_ID, Gr.GPL_Effectivedate, G.GRP_Enrolltype, G.GRP_Name, G.GRP_ID, G.GRP_Executive
FROM groupsreview gr
INNER JOIN groups g on gr.grp_ID = g.grp_ID
WHERE (GRP_ENROLLTYPE = 1) and (gp.gpl_effectivedate >= '4/30/2014' and gp.gpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015')
order by grp_name asc
```

This code gives me a list of every GPL_ID that I want (based off GRP_Enrolltype = 1) that falls within my desired date range

I basically would like to combine the two codes so that the 2nd set of code adds another column that has a count based off the fist code

Comment: Couldn't you just add `GROUP BY GPL_ID` to the first query? ...and MySQL server tends to not like dates in that format. ...and what table is GPL_ID from?

Comment: I'm new to sql, so not 100% sure i follow. if i add the group by gpl_id to the first query it will only give me that 1 gpl_id since it's hardcoded. the process to get to the gpl_id is in code 2

Comment: gpl_id is in table GP (groupspolicy)

Comment: By taking out the `GPL_ID = 20179` and adding the group by you would get the count for each GPL_ID.

Comment: I meant which table is the gpl_id field from in the first query. And similarly, which table is GRP_ENROLLTYPE from in the second query?

Comment: GPL_ID is in  membersapplication and in groupsreview. I can't group by GPL_ID in the first one because there are over 8000 GPL_ID's with over 5mil people, it takes the first code to cipher through them.

Comment: generally it doesn't matter how many records you have in tables. What is matter - what do you need? just tell us in 2 words what is your expected result?

Comment: GRP_Enrolltype is in groups only

Comment: update it in your original post question, not in comment

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but I can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        count(*) as count, GPL_ID
    FROM
        membersapplication ma
    inner join members mb ON mb.mbr_id = ma.mbr_id
    where
        (ma.mpl_effectivedate >= '2/01/2015'
            and ma.mpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015')
            and (ma.mpl_cancellationdate is null)
    GROUP BY GPL_ID) T1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Gr.GPL_ID,
            Gr.GPL_Effectivedate,
            G.GRP_Enrolltype,
            G.GRP_Name,
            G.GRP_ID,
            G.GRP_Executive
    FROM
        groupsreview gr
    inner join groups g ON gr.grp_ID = g.grp_ID
    WHERE
        (GRP_ENROLLTYPE = 1)
            and (gp.gpl_effectivedate >= '4/30/2014'
            and gp.gpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015')) T2 
   ON T1.GPL_ID = T2.GPL_ID
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries, unless TOP is also specified.

Comment: try removing ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Seems you really just need add `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
SELECT ma.GPL_ID, count(*) as count
FROM membersapplication ma
INNER JOIN members mb 
ON mb.mbr_id = ma.mbr_id
where (ma.mpl_effectivedate >= '2/01/2015' and ma.mpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015') 
AND (ma.mpl_cancellationdate is null)
GROUP BY ma.GPL_ID
```

Comment: He probably needs to join to another table or two to get only the groups that satisfy `GRP_ENROLLTYPE = 1`.

Comment: Myabe yes, maybe no. Since *So this is the first method i've been using, but it only works for 1 group at a time* maybe OP just confused us by 2nd query :-)

Comment: sorry, it's hard to keep up. this didn't work either. the second query is what gives me the details for the first query, if i could put the 1st query into the 2nd as 1 extra column, the results from the 2nd query would be sufficient, however i can't run the 1st query without the 2nd since that would run too many groups. i hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. But I would double check the dates, I just used the ones you supplied; they don't match, and I am not sure if they should:

```
SELECT ma.GPL_ID, count(*) as count
FROM groups g
INNER JOIN groupsreview AS gr ON g.grp_ID = gr.grp_ID 
INNER JOIN membersapplication AS ma ON gr.GPL_ID = ma.GPL_ID
INNER JOIN members AS mb ON mb.mbr_id = ma.mbr_id
WHERE g.GRP_ENROLLTYPE = 1 
   AND gr.gpl_effectivedate BETWEEN 20140430 AND 20150430
   AND ma.mpl_effectivedate BETWEEN 20150201 and 20150430 
   AND ma.mpl_cancellationdate IS NULL
GROUP BY ma.GPL_ID
;
```

Judging from your question's wording, it feels a little odd to group by `GPL_ID` instead of `grp_ID`.

Comment: the grp_id will repeat, the gpl_id will not. the gpl_id gives the grp_id a date range (for instance, if grp_id is Tacos, there are people in tacos from 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, etc..., the gpl_id defines the date and ties to the grp_id. I'm going to test this in a moment. (i just got bombarded on my end)

Comment: Judging from a comment you made to another answer, I am guessing you are using MS SQL. This should work for the most part, since it uses fairly standard SQL, but it was designed with MySQL in mind; so you might have to put the date formats back the way they were (and I am not positive MS SQL supports `BETWEEN`.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should approach this by combining joins and then grouping on GPL_ID along with a having clause. Here's what  came up with.

```
SELECT Gr.GPL_ID, Gr.GPL_Effectivedate, G.GRP_Enrolltype, G.GRP_Name, G.GRP_ID, G.GRP_Executive
count(*) as grp_count
FROM membersapplication ma
INNER JOIN members mb on mb.mbr_id = ma.mbr_id
INNER JOIN groupsreview gr on mb.GPL_ID = gr.GPL_ID
INNER JOIN groups g on gr.grp_ID = g.grp_ID
WHERE (GRP_ENROLLTYPE = 1) and (gp.gpl_effectivedate >= '4/30/2014' and gp.gpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015')
GROUP BY Gr.GPL_ID, Gr.GPL_Effectivedate, G.GRP_Enrolltype, G.GRP_Name, G.GRP_ID, G.GRP_Executive
HAVING (ma.mpl_effectivedate >= '2/01/2015' and ma.mpl_effectivedate <= '4/30/2015') and (ma.mpl_cancellationdate is null)
order by grp_name asc
```

Hopefully this helps